# awk: skip number of lines and apply a script on the remaining

Tags: awk

How do I skip the first 7 lines (rows) and apply a script on the remaining lines? I tried the below script but unfortunately it removes everything in the file and makes it empty.

`awk 'NR > 7 { $1="XD"$1}' file> temp && mv temp file`

Comment: you need to do a print as well, e.g.  ```awk 'NR > 7 { $1="XD"$1; print $0}' file```. And if you need the first 7 lines as well, add a rule like ```NR <= 7 { print }```

Comment: @Ronald It applies my script starting from line 8 as expected. However, it removes the first 7 lines from the file. the first 7 line should remain in the file without any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off the mark. Just append `1` to your script (this will cause the `$0` to be printed):

```
awk 'NR > 7 { $1="XD"$1} 1' file> temp && mv temp file
```

Comment: Works as intended. Can you explain what the 1 does? Any idea on how to preserve the file format? Thank you.

Comment: @sam_alloy It is a common `awk` idiom to print the current `$0`. An `awk` script is a series of "condition-action" pairs. In this script, the `1` at the end is a "condition" (which is always true) with an empty "action". An empty "action" is equivalent to `print`, which is equivalent to `print $0`.

Comment: @sam_alloy `Any idea on how to preserve the file format?`: Can you show a sample input line for this?

Answer (score 0):

> skip number of lines

Use [`next` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html) in action to skip line

> apply a script on the remaining

Your script does alter field value, but does not `print` it

Let `file.txt` content be

```
1 10 100
2 20 200
3 30 300
4 40 400
5 50 500
6 60 600
7 70 700
8 80 800
9 90 900
```

then

```
awk 'NR<=7{next}{$1="XD"$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
XD8 80 800
XD9 90 900
```

Observe that pattern-action pair with `next` is before other actions.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: It applies my script starting from line 8 as expected. However, it removes the first 7 lines from the file. the first 7 line should remain in the file without any change.

Comment: @sam_alloy then replace `next` using `print;next`

Answer (score 0):

full parameterized `awk`-based solution :::

1. # rows to skip   `"__"`
2. string to prepend `"___"`

> ```
> gawk '(__<NR) *  ($_=___$_)^_' FS='^$' __=7 ___='XD'  # gawk/nawk
> mawk '(__<NR) * ($!_=___$_)^_' FS='^$' __=7 ___='XD'  # any mawk
> ```

```
XD8 80 800
XD9 90 900
```